# Rails Queries Made By User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a rails app where users can post, must like a form. I want users to be able to search through the posts with a text field, and then all records will be returned where the post content is similar to the user query. For example, a user enters:

```
'albert einstein atomic bomb'
```

Then, I want a to run a query where every word is checked, along with the query itself. Something like:

```
query_result = Hash.new
query_result << Post.where('content ILIKE ?', "%albert%")
query_result << Post.where('content ILIKE ?', "%einstein%")
query_result << Post.where('content ILIKE ?', "%atomic%")
query_result << Post.where('content ILIKE ?', "%bomb%")
query_result << Post.where('content ILIKE ?', "%albert einstein atomic bomb%")
```

This will not work of course, but I hope you get the idea. Any and all input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#readme) gem for stuff like this. Once it's setup you can do searches like so

```
# Posts with the exact phrase "great pizza"
Post.search do
  fulltext '"great pizza"'
end

# One word can appear between the words in the phrase, so "great big pizza"
# also matches, in addition to "great pizza"
Post.search do
  fulltext '"great pizza"' do
    query_phrase_slop 1
  end
end
```

and more. See the info in the link.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
query = 'albert einstein atomic bomb'
sub_queries = query.split("\n") << query 

query_results = []
sub_queries.each { |q| query_results << Post.where('content ILIKE ?', "%#{q}%") }
```

You probably need to `flatten` the `query_results` array and `uniq` to remove duplicates.

Comment: This is not going to work since chaining wheres is going to join using AND which implies that it is only going to find content that matches ALL the keywords and not just ANY (they're most likely looking for something that does a bunch of like clauses joined by OR).

Comment: True. But how is this chaining `where`s? Each `where` is done in isolation. The effect would be exactly as the OP intended.